# OpenGL ES (iPhone) multi-texturing (2D) code

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, multitexturing

I have a texture from this PNG:

[image]

And another from this PNG:

[image]

They both have the same blend function:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**I want to see them on one single polygon first.** I just couldn't find a simple example of this. Draw them to different polygons works perfect, but I just cannot "merge" them into one texture. Any working sample codelines would be appreciated well.

**Second problem is to make the specular map's alpha variable.** I can see that I have to texture combine somehow it's alpha with the primary color (created from my variable), but again, have no working example of codes. I began to study glTexEnvi function, but yet I have no any result.

Please, *I beg you for just about 16 lines of code!* I googled the whole net, but still stuck.

The engine I want to implement (working flash sketch on the bottom of the post) is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110101130737/http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/01/07/compactTangram_072_-_tan_rendering_labs/).

Comment: Ok. No multi-texturing. Simply I can't do it. I'm gonna use pre-rendered textures copyed from off-screen framebuffers. Maybe that way would be easier to implement. Hopeso.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact lines of code that you need, but it seems that you were on the right path with glTexEnv... This [book on opengles 1.1](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/ch08.html) talks about it some. I think what you want are texture combiners:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, myTextureObject);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);

// Tell OpenGL which arithmetic operation to use: 
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, <operation>);

// Set the first argument:
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, <source0>);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, <operand0>);

// Set the second argument:
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, <source1>);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB, <operand1>);
```

I don't know if this will accomplish what you want though, you may still need the FBOs to do it right.